# Glide Gif image

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif, android-glide

i want to load a animated gif im my layout and use this code

```
public class Main extends Activity {
ImageView iv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Glide.with(Main.this)
            .load(R.drawable.gif)
            .asGif()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(iv);
}
```

but nothing happens in layout!
log cat :

```
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517): Request threw uncaught throwable
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/disklrucache/DiskLruCache;
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.java:96)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.java:118)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/disklrucache/DiskLruCache;
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.DiskLruCacheWrapper.getDiskCache(DiskLruCacheWrapper.java:59)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.DiskLruCacheWrapper.get(DiskLruCacheWrapper.java:76)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.loadFromCache(DecodeJob.java:215)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeResultFromCache(DecodeJob.java:85)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decodeFromCache(EngineRunnable.java:108)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decode(EngineRunnable.java:99)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.run(EngineRunnable.java:58)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-19 05:50:30.834: E/PriorityExecutor(1517):   ... 3 more
```

i think one class of glide did not load !

Comment: Do you see any errors from Glide in logcat? Also, you should move your image loading to after onCreate - onCreate is mainly for instantiating members of the activity.

Comment: @fejd this is my logcat

Comment: i found that low resolution gif like 250*250 pixel shows correctly but for example 2000*1000 pixel got error

Comment: How are you including Glide in your build? A JAR? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: as a jar file in project propertie